# How to cancel long-running but single-threaded operations

Tags: c#, winforms, cancellation

I see a lot of options for canceling a long-running operation in C#, but each example seems to talk about cancelling parallel (multithreaded) operations or are overly-simple examples, or involve periodically polling for whether a request to cancel the operation was submitted.  I don't think that will work here.

I have a method `BuildZipFile()` which, for now, takes no arguments, but I suspect might need a `CancellationToken` argument. Calling this method does the following. `BuildZipFile()` blocks; execution on the thread doesn't resume until it's done with its work.

1. Files are extracted and added to a zip file. This operation is so quick that I don't want it to be cancelable. If the user requests a cancel, it should ignore the request until the operation is complete, and then skip the rest of `BuildZipFile()` and return (or throw an exception; doesn't matter).
2. Files are processed using something called a "pipeline." This operation *does* take a long time and the user should be able to cancel it. To start this processing, `BuildZipFile()` calls a non-blocking method `Start()` on the pipeline. A pipeline raises `Done` when it's done with its work, so I use an `AutoResetEvent` to block the method until I hear that event, and then release the block.
3. Some more operations similar to item #1: quick-running operations that should not support cancelling.

Here's an overly-simplified implementation:

```
public void BuildZipFile()
{
    // single-threaded operation that is quick and can't be canceled
    DoQuickUncancelableThings();

    // and now a long-running operation that the user SHOULD be able to cancel;
    // it must be possible to interrupt the AutoResetEvent
    var pipeline = GimmeAPipeline();
    var reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    // when the pipeline raises Done, stop blocking the method and resume execution
    pipeline.Done += () => reset.Set(); 
    // define the work to be done
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => pipeline.Start());
    // call pipeline.Start() and block the thread until pipeline.Done is raised
    reset.WaitOne();

    // ...and more quick operations that can't be canceled
    DoMoreQuickUncancelableThings();
}
```

Note that in reality, that middle block of code exists in another class which this one calls.

I can stop the pipeline in this method by calling `pipeline.Stop()` which will indirectly raise the `Done` event once the request to stop it was handled.

So, how can I modify `BuildZipFile()` to support user cancellation? My instinct is to add support for catching an `OperationCanceledException`, but that would allow those quick operations to cancel too, wouldn't it? And, I can't poll for a cancellation request unless I'm missing something because I'm waiting for that `Done` event from `pipeline` to be raised, and the last thing I want to do is poll using a timer to interrupt it.

I have no issues with modifying `BuildZipFile()` to become non-blocking, but the steps within it are very linear. Step #2 can't even start until step #1 is done; the process can't be made parallel. I cannot change how pipelines work; they must remain asynchronous and raise events when they're done.

I'm using .NET 4.5 in a Windows Forms application so I can use pretty much any framework feature I need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Tasks to do want you want.
Check this msdn article,it is very usefull

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a full example in a console application

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
 class Program
 {
    static CancellationTokenSource tokenSource2;
    static CancellationToken ct;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ct = tokenSource2.Token;
        Task myTask = new Task(BuildZipFile);
        myTask.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to cancel");
        Console.ReadLine();
        tokenSource2.Cancel();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void BuildZipFile()
    {
        Task quick1 = new Task(DoQuickUncancelableThings);
        quick1.ContinueWith(ant => DoLongRunnignThings(), ct).ContinueWith(ant => DoMoreQuickUncancelableThings());
        quick1.Start();
    }

    private static void DoMoreQuickUncancelableThings()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Q2");
    }
    private static void DoLongRunnignThings()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Long ended");
    }
    private static void DoQuickUncancelableThings()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Q1");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I should note that Quick2 will run even if LongRunning is cancelled but it is very easy to change it using  task continuation options.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting it, but doesn't that still poll?  It looks like `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` needs to be explicitly called at a certain point to check if it was canceled. Is my only option to check periodically if a cancel was requested, or can I just be notified via an event or something else?

Comment: I don't think there any measurable delay if that's what you're thinking.You can check the BackGroundWorker class if you want to cancel a function using an event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

And a simpler example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Thanks; I ended up using a `CancellationTokenSource` passed into the method, and periodically calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` on it. For my method of blocking using an `AutoResetEvent`, I started a background task that polls every second and does the same thing. I then used a form running in a separate thread so it's responsive that shows progress to the user and has a Cancel button that requests cancellation on the token source.